# How to strcat 1 character from a 2d array to a 1d array

Tags: c, arrays, string

Essentially I'm trying to strcat a letter from a 2d array onto a 1d array. I've got this user inputted grid of letters and from these letters I'm combining them letter by letter into a 1d array and checking it against a dictionary to see if its a valid word.

I've been trying something like

```
strcat(wordTester, board[i][j]);
```

but I keep getting runtime errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can't `strcat` a character (as opposed to a single character string). `strcat` operates on *strings*. A minimal non-empty string is one character + a NUL character. You can do it with `strncat`. Like: `strncat(wordTester, &board[i][j], 1);`. But always need to ensure you don't overflow the destination buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @kaylum really helped, now maybe you could help me with something else? Whenever I copy the letter initially to the 1d array I get some garbage copied as well it seems, so when I print the 1d array it spits out some random symbols followed by the letter copied. I'm guessing this has something to do with how I created my 1d array which is basically char wordTester[16].

Comment: Yes, as I said, `strcat` requires each parameter to be a string. `wordTester` is not initialised so it will contain garbage (not a string). Just initalise it. Easiest way is `char wordTester[16] = "";` BTW, if you are doing this in a loop then a more efficient way to do the copy is just to keep track of an incrementing index for the current end of the string, do a char assignment at that index and then end with a NUL assignment. Doing `strncat` continuously is inefficient as it requires a scan of the dest string for each call to find the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

`strcat()` is for connecting null-terminated string, so passing a character to it will lead to crush because the character will likely converted to an invalid pointer.

Try using this functon:

```
#include <string.h>
char* charcat(char *target, char c) {
    size_t len;
    if (target != NULL) {
        len = strlen(target);
        target[len] = c;
        target[len + 1] = '\0';
    }
    return target;
}
```

Usage (assuming `char wordTester[MAX]; char board[M][N];` where `MAX`, `M` and `N` are properly defined):

```
charcat(wordTester, board[i][j]);
```